# How to pass HttpStatusCode between 2 MVC sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-response-codes

I have 2 `MVC` sites. One (A) is posting to another (B).

`MVC` site A:

```
using (var handler = new WebRequestHandler())
{
    handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            StreamContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent();
            formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Path.GetFileName("some test path")));

            var fileReceiveURL = "URL(B)\SomeController\PostFile";
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(fileReceiveURL, formData).Result;
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Not able to send file to (B). Didn't get a successful response from server.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MVC` site B (SomeController):

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    \\ for testing purpose, just return a bad request response code
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

But at (A). the response (breakpoint at [HttpResponseMessage response...] ) is always "StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1" no matter what HttpStatusCode I set to (B) to send back.

How can I send `HttpStatusCode` between 2 `MVC` sites?

Comment: What version of asp.net-mvc are you using? the site B code should work provided you are using a version previous to asp.net-core. If using asp.net-core then the described behavior would be accurate as that version treats `HttpResponseMessage` returned from actions as models and would default to 200 when called. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce and confirm the problem.

Comment: both sites are MVC 5.

Comment: What is the content of the response then given that it returns 200. The content could provide a clue.

Comment: You are using `PostAsync`, so while debugging I am not one hundred percent sure but it is normal to see the response ok. Because by default initially it is set to ok till get the final response.

Comment: Please try checking it from Fiddler, Postman or Advanced Rest Client first instead of MVC site.

Comment: Thanks for all the comment. But at the end, the status code received by the MVC site is going to determine what is logged (whether error has occured). I understand that I need to check with Fiddler, wireshark, etc.

Comment: @ibubi, if PostAsync should not be used, what should I use?

Comment: try it with the Post method (sync one). `client.Post`

Comment: Thanks to Nkosi (I check the response.Content) and ibubi (I googled further on PostAsync). I am able to get the proper response code now. Will post my solution to answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the response object...

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(fileReceiveURL, formData).Result;
```

### response will always return 200 OK.

need to check

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(fileReceiveURL, formData);
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

`response.Content` contains the proper `HttpStatusCode` from site B.